# Strain energy of plate bending

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, stress-strain

I am currently doing some research for my university thesis and I am dealing with plates.
Right now I am trying to figure out the potential (strain) energy of a plate under bending.

So basically I found a paper which explains exactly this but the following part is confusing me:

[image]

My question is:

Usually the bending strain can be expressed as $\Delta U = \dfrac{1}{2} M \cdot \Delta \Theta$. But from geometry, $\Delta \Theta$ should be: $\dfrac{\Delta x}{R}$. Why does the paper use $\Delta x \cdot R$ instead?

I am very happy for a any help or explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper has an error.  The second derivative of the displacement function is the *inverse* of the radius curvature, not the curvature itself:
$$
\frac{1}{R} = \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}.
$$
So the final equation is still correct.

Comment: Ohh yeah that makes sense. I didnt notice that! Thank you very much :)